# Undefined Variable in switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a API in order to get stats off of Battlefield. The level returns a number and I am using a switch to determine the name of that level so no matter what the username or if the user ranks up then it will be updated using the switch. However, when I am accessing the 'rank' variable it doesn't appear as it says level is undefined so the switch isn't working at all.

```
var rank;
var level;

$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxSearch();
});

function ajaxSearch() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: 'false',
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.result).each(function(index, value) {
                level = value.rank.number;
                console.log(level);
            });
        }
    })
}

function workoutRank() {
    switch (level) {
        case '0':
            rank = 'Recruit';
        break;
        case '1':
            rank = 'Private';
        break;
        case '2':
            rank = 'Private II';
        break;
        case '3':
            rank = 'Private III';
        break;
        case '4':
            rank = 'Private IV';
        break;
        case '19':
            rank = 'Corporal X';
        break;
    }
}

$('#lookup-btn').click(function() {
   workoutRank();
   console.log(rank);
});
```

This is a image of the console:

[image: Console]

Comment: It's a the top sorry, will update the question now.

Comment: @AndrewLi Question updated.

Comment: uhm. you are looping, and setting level on each iteration. level can only contain one value, why are you looping?

Comment: Add the switch to the success of the Ajax. Ajax is async!!

Comment: @LelioFaieta so is clicking an element, it's possible that the ajax will be done before then.

Comment: @cmiotk symptoms suggest that etiher your ajax request is failing, you're clicking the button too early (before the ajax is complete,) or the data returned from the ajax isn't what you expect.

Comment: Ajax is definitely working, as in the console I am logging the level which is returning the integer result (19) it seems to be that, the function workoutRank isn't receiving the value of level, setting the level = '0' will log "Recruit" in the console, so the variable isn't being passed but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The Ajax call has not finished (or it terminated without success)
2. The data returned by the Ajax call is not what you're expecting. In particular, if your `level` values are integers, then your case values should also be integers:

   ```
   switch (level) {
       case 0: // not '0'
           rank = 'Recruit';
           break;
       // etc
   ```

Comment: It was literally the case using '0' etc, how could I have forgotten that?! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxSearch` is asynchronous, so `level` is not guaranteed to have a value when you call `workoutRank`. You need to make sure you understand that these two things happen in parallel.

Instead, call `workoutRank` when the `ajax` call has returned, or use `promises` to ensure the value will resolve.

**edit:** the question was edited to show this is not necessarily the case, but I will leave this up as it could certainly be an issue for someone else experiencing this in the future

Comment: The ajax is done on document load, so it should return a value straight away and if it is none existent it should = to 0 but it seems that this isn't the case and level is = 19 when it is producing the error of undefined.

Comment: That code was not there when I wrote my answer! it was edited in after

Comment: This very well could be "a" problem if the button is clicked really quickly, but unlikely.

Comment: @cmiotk - The ajax call may be _initiated_ on document load, but that doesn't mean that the return value is available right away. And the global variables will be `undefined`, not `0`, until a value is assigned to them. It would be best to disable `lookup-btn` until the ajax call finishes.